# php equations in statements with double = problems

Tags: php

I've got some weird actions from my php script and finally figured out that this following statement makes problems. Because 0 is equal some string in php.

```
if(0 == "whats Up?")
{
  echo 42;
}
```

With triple "=" it do what I expected. It is possible for you to give me a briefly answer what is the reason and idea behind this behavior of php? Why did they implement php like this?

I mean I know that 1 == "1" is true and 1 === "1" is not. This is also in python. I also learn from somewhere that 0 could be understandable as false but this example above has no explication for me. But I am sure that you know it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). The second operand gets converted to an integer and `0` `==` `0` is `true`.

```
var_dump((int) "whats Up?"); // int(0)
```